# Can't update Zustand state using setState function

Tags: reactjs, state, zustand

In `Comp1` when i hover mouse on it i want the state to change to true (I'm passing `true` param to it). Also i want to ensure that by doing so this will not cause the `Comp2` component to re-render.

My understanding was that if i do like so `useStoreOnHover.setState({ onComp1: true })` it should work but it does not :(

I have also tried with `const onComp1Set = useStoreOnHover((s) => s.onComp1Set)` but still same :(

The only way i was able to get it working is by `const { onComp1Set } = useStoreOnHover()` but I'm trying to avoid these type of de-structuring because it also triggers re-renders to other components.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-grass-qxrv8

```
import create, { GetState, SetState } from "zustand";

type typeStoreOnHover = {
  onComp1: boolean;
  onComp1Set: (val: boolean) => void;

  onComp2: boolean;
};

export const useStoreOnHover = create<typeStoreOnHover>(
  (set: SetState<typeStoreOnHover>, get: GetState<typeStoreOnHover>) => {
    return {
      onComp1: false,
      onComp1Set: (val) => set({ onComp1: val }),

      onComp2: false
    };
  }
);

const Comp1 = () => {
  const onComp1 = useStoreOnHover.getState().onComp1;
  // const onComp1Set = useStoreOnHover((s) => s.onComp1Set);

  console.log("Comp 1", onComp1);
  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        // onComp1Set(true);
        useStoreOnHover.setState({ onComp1: true });
      }}
    >
      Comp 1 {onComp1 ? "True" : "False"}
    </div>
  );
};

const Comp2 = () => {
  const onComp2 = useStoreOnHover((s) => s.onComp2);

  console.log("Comp 2", onComp2);

  return <div>Comp 2 </div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Comp1 />
      <Comp2 />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to zustand documentation, this should be the actual approach,

```js
const onComp1 = useStoreOnHover((s) => s.onComp1);
```

I have tested it on your CodeSandBox link and it worked.

I am not familiar with the zustand library but this might help you.

Comment: sorry but this one is not using onComp1Set to set to true, you just getting a value but not setting it

Comment: and also i've mentioned that const onComp1Set = useStoreOnHover((s) => s.onComp1Set) will not work, i still get re-renders in my project but on this example it does work. so looking for alternative

Comment: Oh! My bad! I thought you were trying to get the latest value! But your set function really works! The issue is how you are trying to get the data from the state. Actually this line - `useStoreOnHover.getState().onComp1` doesn't update the value when you are changing it using your set function. That's why I showed in my answer how it should be taken from the state. Also, it doesn't re-render other components. Check my forked solution here - https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-butterfly-6kzwe

Comment: right you are right, it's working now, i'm sure i have tried this before but i was not working, so then found more stuff that causing this. but yeah this method works.